# InvalidCastException when retrieving object from sqlite table using Linq2DB

Tags: c#, sqlite, system.data.sqlite, linq2db

I have a problem trying to get records from a Sqlite table using Linq2db+SQLite, here is my table below

```
CREATE TABLE LogEntry 
(
Time DATETIME NOT NULL ON CONFLICT ROLLBACK DEFAULT (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 
Reference STRING NOT NULL ON CONFLICT ROLLBACK, 
Team STRING, 
Operator STRING, 
ETMachine STRING, 
CheckPoint BOOLEAN DEFAULT (0) NOT NULL
);
```

down is C# code:

```
using (var db = new DataConnection())
  {
        var newItem = new LogEntry()
        {
          CheckPoint = false,
          ETMachine = "232323", // <= cause
          Operator = "asdasd",
          Reference = "asasas",
          Team = "wewe",
          Time = DateTime.Now
        };

        db.Insert<LogEntry>(newItem);

        foreach (var item in db.LogEntries) //<= error occurs here
        {
          MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0}:{1}", item.ID, item.Time));
        }
}
```

and entity

```
    [Table("LogEntry")]
    public partial class LogEntry
  {
    [Column(Name = "ROWID"), NotNull, PrimaryKey, Identity] public int ID { get; set; } // datetime
    [Column, NotNull    ] public DateTime Time       { get; set; } // datetime
        [Column, NotNull    ] public string   Reference  { get; set; } // string(max)
        [Column,    Nullable] public string   Team       { get; set; } // string(max)
        [Column,    Nullable] public string   Operator   { get; set; } // string(max)
        [Column,    Nullable] public string   ETMachine  { get; set; } // string(max)
        [Column, NotNull    ] public bool     CheckPoint { get; set; } // boolean
    }
```

I get

```
'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in System.Data.SQLite.dll
Additional information: Specified cast is not valid.
@ System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.VerifyType(Int32 i, DbType typ)
@ System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.GetString(Int32 i)
@ lambda_method(Closure , IDataReader )
@ LinqToDB.Expressions.ConvertFromDataReaderExpression.ColumnReader.GetValue(IDataReader dataReader) dans i:\linq2db\Source\Expressions\ConvertFromDataReaderExpression.cs:ligne 128
@ lambda_method(Closure , QueryContext , IDataContext , IDataReader , Expression , Object[] )
@ LinqToDB.Linq.Query`1.<Map>d__6a.MoveNext() dans i:\linq2db\Source\Linq\Query.cs:ligne 1218
@ Peel.FrmMain.Testdb2() dans C:\Users\Administrateur\Documents\Work\Projects\PeeL\src\Peel\FrmMain.cs:ligne 67
```

I searched a little bit and found out that the issue rises when a string field of the table have numeric values ex. `ETMachine` property above, although the value is passed as string literal.
Here, if I change the `232323` to `232a323` it will work fine.

My question, How can I force Linq2db to insert the value as string and not numeric?
Or, How can I force the Linq2DB to get values as its appropriate field type?

BTW target framework is 4.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the problem, the issue was in column datatype `STRING`, after I changed it to `TEXT` it worked fine.

According to SQLite Documentation...

> 2.1 Determination Of Column Affinity
>
> The affinity of a column is determined by the declared type of the column, according to the following rules in the order shown:
>
> - If the declared type contains the string "INT" then it is assigned INTEGER affinity.
> - If the declared type of the column contains any of the strings "CHAR", "CLOB", or "TEXT" then that column has TEXT affinity. Notice
>     that the type VARCHAR contains the string "CHAR" and is thus assigned
>     TEXT affinity.
> - If the declared type for a column contains the string "BLOB" or if no type is specified then the column has affinity BLOB.
> - If the declared type for a column contains any of the strings "REAL", "FLOA", or "DOUB" then the column has REAL affinity.
> - Otherwise, the affinity is NUMERIC. Note that the order of the rules for determining column affinity is important. A column whose
>     declared type is "CHARINT" will match both rules 1 and 2 but the first
>     rule takes precedence and so the column affinity will be INTEGER.

In my case it's `string` which does not contain `CHAR` then the type is `NUMERIC`.